# Neo4j cypher MATCH query not working

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have created following Indexes on Label *Student* in my Embedded `graphDb`

```
Schema schema = graphDb.schema();    
indexDefinition = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label("Student")).on("NodeType").create();
indexDefinition = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label("Student")).on("Marks").create();
```

While using cypher **MATCH** query

This works : `match (n:Student) return n;`

This also works : `match (n:Student) where n.Marks<30 return n;`

But, This fails : `match (n:Student) where n.Marks=30 return n;`

And this too:  `match (n:Student) where n.Marks='30' return n;`

Curious thing is this one works:

`start n=node(127) match (n:Student) where n.Marks=30 return n;`

*Works: I get the expected results, Fails : No result*

Can anyone explain this behaviour, as all the properties are already Indexed(Label) and the cypher should return the desired result.

I have also checked if the properties are Indexed or not for the label using :

```
Label label1 = DynamicLabel.label("Student");
System.out.println(schema.getIndexes(label1));
```

I am executing the cypher queries using [this](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html) approach.

**[EDIT] Node creation:**

```
Integer marks = 30;
Label label = DynamicLabel.label("Student");
tx = graphDb.beginTx();
Node studentNode = graphDb.createNode(label);
studentNode.setProperty("NodeType", "Student");
studentNode.setProperty("Marks", marks);
tx.success();
```

Comment: I've tried it out and this just works. I did have to correct your cypher queries so they have parentheses around the node 'n' and removed a couple of ';' where they shouldn't have been.

Comment: How did you create your node with the Label 'Student' and the value for 'Marks' ? What Neo4j version are you using?

Comment: I have edited the question, find it there.

Comment: I am using neo4j-community-2.0.0-M03.

Answer (score 1):

This just works, see the following code snippet. What's different in your script?

```
final GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase();
final ExecutionEngine cypher = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
    Schema schema = graphDb.schema();
    //schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label("Student")).on("NodeType").create();
    schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label("Student")).on("marks").create();
    Label label1 = DynamicLabel.label("Student");
    System.out.println(schema.getIndexes(label1));
    tx.success();
}
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
    Node node = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("Student"));
    node.setProperty("marks", 20);
    node = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("Student"));
    node.setProperty("marks", 30);
    node = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("Student"));
    node.setProperty("marks", 40);
    System.out.println(cypher.execute("match (n:Student) return n").dumpToString());
            System.out.println(cypher.execute("match (n:Student) where n.marks<30 return n;").dumpToString());
    System.out.println(cypher.execute("match (n:Student) where n.marks=30 return n;").dumpToString());
    System.out.println(cypher.execute("match (n:Student) where n.marks='30' return n;").dumpToString());
    tx.success();
}
```

Script output:

```
[IndexDefinition[label:Student, on:marks]]
+-------------------+
| n                 |
+-------------------+
| Node[0]{marks:20} |
| Node[1]{marks:30} |
| Node[2]{marks:40} |
+-------------------+
3 rows

+-------------------+
| n                 |
+-------------------+
| Node[0]{marks:20} |
+-------------------+
1 row

+-------------------+
| n                 |
+-------------------+
| Node[1]{marks:30} |
+-------------------+
1 row

+---+
| n |
+---+
+---+
0 row
```

Comment: Timmy, your Index definition doesn't match the data, property names are case sensitive. "marks" vs. "Marks"

Comment: But you're right the better property name would be "marks" as it is lowercase camel-case.

Comment: You probably want to re-run it to correct the output too :)

Comment: The code is almost same, I was not surrounding the node with parentheses, but doing that didn't help either.

Comment: Any thoughts about how this query would work : start n=node(127) match (n:Student) where n.Marks=30 return n;

Comment: Leave out the MATCH clause: `start n=node(127) where n.Marks=30 return n`;